# Get Hourly based sum in django

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

I have a model which contains two fields **DateTimeField** and an **IntegerField**.
I want to sum the total integers on the basis of hour.

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField()
    relative_change = models.IntegerField()
```

Now i want to query the **modelA** so that it will return the total sum of relative_change for each hour,What's the good way to do it?
I checked this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56302262/aggregate-hourly-count-based-on-hour-in-datetime-field-in-django)  but i am not clear what is 'hour' there.
The Output should look like

```
[
   {
    "time":"9-10",
    "relative_change":"20"
   },
   {
    "time":"10-11",
    "relative_change":"40"
   },
   {
    "time":"11-12",
    "relative_change":12
   }
]
```

Comment: **count** or **sum of relative_change**?

Comment: yes ,sum of relative_change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

queryset = (
    ModelA
    .objects
    .values('date_time__hour')
    .annotate(relative_change_sum=Sum('relative_change')
)
```

You should expect the following result:

```
<QuerySet [{
    'date_time__hour': 9,
    'relative_change_sum': 20,
}, {
    'date_time__hour': 10,
    'relative_change_sum': 40,
}]
```

Here's more details about the 'hour' lookup:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#hour